# Spark Java append data to Hive table

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I'm facing some problem when trying to append data to an hive table.
I declared the session correctly the session: I can retrieve data from the table

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")

                .enableHiveSupport()
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();
```

When trying to append some data using `df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("sample.test_table");` I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: hive. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

What I'm missing?

EDIT:
Using  `df.write().insertInto("prova2.test_table");` works, no idea how it works

Comment: What are the spark and hive versions you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveAsTable()` seems to not work as you intend. Try this instead,

Register a temp table

```java
df.registerTempTable("sample.temptable")
```

Create and insert data if the table does not exitsts already,

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample.test_table as select * from sample.temptable")
```

OR simpty create it without inserting any value so that you can rerun the code without any exceptions

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample.test_table")
```

Insert data (Table should exist)

```
sqlContext.sql("insert into table sample.test_table select * from sample.temptable")
```

Drop temp table

```
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample.temptable")
```

Read more on [temporary table usage](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/hive-temporary-table-usage-and-how-to-create/)

Comment: Thanks, sounds a little bit strange but it works!

Comment: Indeed. Glad it helped.

Comment: By chance, do you know which is the rational behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess what `saveAsTable()` is trying to do is to create a new table. Since the table already exists it might be failing to do so. I think it's something similar with `insertInto()` too. Check this out. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Inserting-data-from-a-dataframe-to-an-existing-Hive-Table/td-p/61543

Comment: Thanks, `insertInto()` unluckily has some peculiar behaviour with column position...